# Trigger to fire after Insert/Update/Delete not firing after Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I added the following trigger to a table but it's only firing after `Update` and `Delete`, but not for `Insert` - why?

I tried changed the `AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE` to `FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE`

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[EPRTrigger] 
ON [dbo].[TriggerTable]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
NOT FOR REPLICATION
AS
    DECLARE @triggerType varchar(6), 
            @insert varchar(6) = 'Insert', 
            @update varchar(6) = 'Update', 
            @triggerTypeID int, 
            @delete varchar(6) = 'Delete'

    DECLARE @insertedHasRows bit, @deletedHasRows bit
    DECLARE @isInsert bit, @isUpdate bit, @isDelete bit

    SET @insertedHasRows = (SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    SET @deletedHasRows = (SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    SET @triggerType = 
        CASE 
            WHEN @insertedHasRows = 1 AND @deletedHasRows = 0 
                THEN @insert 
            WHEN @insertedHasRows = 1 AND @deletedHasRows = 1 
                THEN @update
            WHEN @insertedHasRows = 0 AND @deletedHasRows = 1 
                THEN @delete
        END

IF (@triggerType = @insert OR @triggerType = @update)
BEGIN
    -- take action
END
ELSE IF  (@triggerType = @delete)
BEGIN
    -- take action
END
```

Comment: Honestly, I find that if you need different logic for `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` triggers, it's better to have separate triggers for each DML operation. Here it seems you want a separate trigger for `AFTER DELETE`, as you have the same branch for `INSERT` and `UPDATE`.

Comment: @Larnu yes I just had the same thought, I was trying to rationalise but maybe it's just not worth the effort

Comment: Looks like the INSERT branch fires as expected? https://dbfiddle.uk/CJ71gsCJ

Comment: AFTER and FOR are the same thing. I expect that something you haven’t shown us (e.g. code hidden behind `— take action`) is the part that’s not running as expected.

Comment: Also, your logic could be vastly simplified... https://dbfiddle.uk/FSI1CVo7

Comment: Please give a [mcve] preferably as a https://dbfiddle.uk, because at the moment we cannot reproduce your issue